# Farey Sequence Length - C++ - Time Limit Exceeded [CPU > 1.00 s] - Kattis.com

Tags: c++, algorithm, sequence

I have a problem with this code at runtime.
[problem's link](https://open.kattis.com/problems/farey)

```cpp
// problem's link: https://open.kattis.com/problems/farey
#include <iostream>
int f(int n){
  int my_sum = 0;
  for(int k = 2; k < n + 1; k++) my_sum += f(n / k);
  return (n * (n + 3)) / 2 - my_sum;
}
int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin>> n;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int k, num;
    std::cin>> k >> num;
    std::cout<< k << " " << f(num) <<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I followed this formula: a(n) = n(n+3)/2 - Sum(k = 2 to n, a([n/k]))
[mentioned here](https://oeis.org/A005728)

```
Sample Input 1:
4
1 6
2 15
3 57
4 9999
```

```
Sample Output 1:
1 13
2 73
3 1001
4 30393487
```

I have passed this sample.

some tests, n = 1000 to 1500
[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lobr.png)

Comment: `1500 * 1500 = 2 250 000` -- That's how many iterations that nested `for` loop is doing.  Most of these questions you get from those websites have either some mathematical trick, algorithm, or data structure as their solution.  These questions are designed so that naive nested for-loop solutions work for small data, but will fail for large datasets.

Comment: function `f(.)` is called several times for the same value. You may try memoization